Trouble getting my JS function to validate my HTML form
I've been having so much trouble getting my JavaScript to check that the emails in my HTML form match and display results. I've tried doing it like the zyBook for my class shows, but I just get nothing.
I tried to have the function compare the input of #email and #cemail and change the background color of the field to green when they matched and to red when they didn't match. I tried to create an event listener to run the function whenever the input for #cemail changed. I'm using Visual Studio, and one of the main problems that I notice is that when I add .value or .style or anything like it, they don't get suggested as a method of the objects in the function. It seems like I'm referencing something that doesn't exist, but the IDs match, so I don't know why it doesn't register.
Here is the relevant code:


    let cemail = document.querySelector("#cemail").value;
    let formWidget = cemail.addEventListener("change", checkEmail)


    function checkEmail(){
        let email = document.querySelector("#email").value;

        if (email.trim() === cemail.trim()) {
            email.style.backgroundColor = "green";
            cEmail.style.backgroundColor = "green";
            return true;
        } else {
            email.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            cEmail.style.backgroundColor = "red";        }

    }
<form id="userInfo">
    <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="John"><br>
    <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>,
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Doe"><br>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="abc123@gmail
.com"><br>
    <label for="cemail">Confrim Email:</label>
    <input type="text" id="cemail" name="cemail"
placeholder="abc123@gmail.com"><br>
    <label for="question">Write Question:</label>
    <textarea id="question" name="question" size="50"
    placeholder="My question is..."></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>




Check your devTool for error : cemail.addEventListener is not a function

You are confusing DOM element and its value

JavaScript is case-sensitive: cemail != cEmail

addEventListener() doesn't return a value. What are you expecting formWidget to contain?

I think it is better to use e.target.value for the confirmation email input like this you can instantly show to user if it is matching or not while typing.


let confEmail = document.querySelector("#cemail")
let enteredEmail = document.querySelector("#email");


function checkEmail(e){
    let email = enteredEmail.value;
    const value = e.target.value
    if (email.trim() === value.trim()) {
        enteredEmail.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        confEmail.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    
    } else {
        enteredEmail.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        confEmail.style.backgroundColor = "red";        
    }
}

confEmail.addEventListener("input",checkEmail)
    <form id="userInfo">
        <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="John"><br>
        <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>,
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Doe"><br>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="abc123@gmail
    .com"><br>
        <label for="cemail">Confrim Email:</label>
        <input type="text" id="cemail" name="cemail"
    placeholder="abc123@gmail.com"><br>
        <label for="question">Write Question:</label>
        <textarea id="question" name="question" size="50"
        placeholder="My question is..."></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>




the querySelector returns

Element object representing the first element in the document that matches the specified set of CSS selectors, or null is returned if there are no matches.

meaning you get all sorts of attributes and methods to interact with the feild
You had to keep an reference to the Element and access its value each time you wanted to compare with something. and using the same reference, you'll be able to update its attributs (like bg color)
once you remove the .value VS Code should help you with intellisense
here's the working code :
    let cemail = document.querySelector("#cemail");
    let formWidget = cemail.addEventListener("change", checkEmail)
    
    
    function checkEmail(){
        let email = document.querySelector("#email");
    
        if (email.value.trim() === cemail.value.trim()) {
            email.style.backgroundColor = "green";
            cemail.style.backgroundColor = "green";
            return true;
        } else {
            email.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            cemail.style.backgroundColor = "red";        }
    
    }


You can use the build in form validation. Combine that with a function that copies the value of the email form field into the pattern attribute of the cemail form field. Then the only way to get it to validate is if the cemail matches the pattern.


const form = document.forms['userInfo'];

form.email.addEventListener('input', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  form.cemail.pattern = e.target.value;
});

form.addEventListener('input', e => {
  if (e.target.validity.valid) {
    e.target.classList.remove('invalid');
  }
});

form.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  e.target.classList.add('invalid');
},true);
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

input.invalid {
  background-color: red;
}
<form id="userInfo">
  <label>First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="John"></label>
  <label>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Doe"></label>
  <label>Email: <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="abc123@gmail
.com" required></label>
  <label>Confrim Email: <input type="text" name="cemail"
      placeholder="abc123@gmail.com" required
      title="emails must be identical"></label>
  <label>Write Question: <textarea name="question" size="50"
    placeholder="My question is..."></textarea></label>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>



